# Why does my piezoelectric actuator stick at low temperatures?

Tags: design, temperature, actuator

I use a piezoelectric actuator on an experimental set up. At low temperatures (Lower than 0 Celsius), the piezo will freeze. Meaning, it will actuate about half way, and then stop moving. Other than the temperature, other conditions have changed.

It is possible that this sticking is in fact some lubricant in the device. I

Can someone comment upon any possible physical origin for a piezo to stick like this?

Comment: You've half-answered yourself: look for contaminants, including condensed water vapor.

Comment: How does one "look"? I don't see any visually.